# No consistent word-breaking in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, line-breaks, word-break

Please take a look in Firefox at [the development site here](http://www.adglomera.be/AK7/projecten/accountantskantoor-verschaeren-mertens/).

The same phrase "Accountantskantoor verschaeren-mertens" is shown twice, once in the sidebar and once in the upper right corner. As you can see the line breaks at different positions. I've tested in Chrome, IE and Firefox and this only occurs in Firefox.

Any thought on how to make it consistent? I've tried the following but it didn't work.

```
word-break: normal;
```

Comment: I should mention that I'm looking for a sollution that will fix this on all pages of this Wordpress site. So simply adjusting the (max-)width of the upper right title is not a good fix as titles will come along in different lenghts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather mysterious, because Firefox is clearly *hyphenating* the text in the upper right corner: there is a hyphen at the end of first line, indicating word division made. It’s not something that `word-break` would cause (it brutally breaks strings instead of proper word divisioon).

Yet there is nothing that suggests hyphenation in the code, unless I’m missing something.

But setting the following on the element prevents Firefox from hyphenating:

```
-moz-hyphens: manual
```

Presumably Firefox now has some defaults that cause automatic hyphenation in some situations (possibly `-moz-hyphens: auto` with some fancy selector). And since Firefox still does not use [`hyphens`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens) as the property name, the vendor-prefixed property needs to be used.

Setting the value to `manual` allows a break after a hyphen as well as the effect of soft hyphens. To disallow even them, use the value `none` instead.

Comment: It turned out the following CSS-rule caused it: `.site-content article { -moz-hyphens: auto; }`. I'm using the TwentyTwelve theme by the way. Overriding this with `.site-content article { -moz-hyphens: manual; }` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this feature differs in browsers so IMO the only solution is to use hyphenator.js There is also a 
**[hyphenator wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyphenator/)**